# Como separar por filas un texto en plano excel

Tags: excel, macros, microsoft-office

agradecerles de antemano por las respuestas.

Estoy teniendo un problema al intentar separar por filas unos datos en plano, estuve tratando con macro pero no logro ponerlo, paso en foto un ejemplo de como tengo los datos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y como se desea tener:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Impórtalo usando como carácter delimitador la barra vertical

Comment: Hola ¿Qué versión de Excel usas? ¿Probaste con Power Query? ¿o acaso necesariamente requieres macros? Saludos.

Comment: Al usar un carácter de limitador solo me separa la la primera fila de forma horizontal y no me arroja el resto de filas

Comment: Estoy usando la última versión de excel, cómo podría emplear power query? No estoy conectando a una BD

Comment: Confirma que es un archivo txt y que lo que se ve en la foto sí son pipes (|) que separan los datos

Comment: No es un archivo txt, es una fila de excel, donde asi se tienen los datos en duro. Si son pipes |

Comment: Ah, ya, entonces es un archivo con una sola fila, pero en tu imagen parecían varias. Si subes un ejemplo a un drive y compartes el enlace, al menos con una parte de los datos, será super fácil darte la solución.

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir el txt original?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

te paso modificacion

```
Sub Extrae()
Dim rango As Range
Dim Lineas As Variant
Dim Textos As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim ii As Long
Dim Fila As Long
Set rango = Hoja1.Range("A1:A9")
Fila = 1

Hoja2.Range("A" & Fila & ":J" & Range("A" & Fila + 1).End(xlDown).Row).Clear

For Each rango In rango
 Lineas = Split(rango.Value, Chr(10))
  
  For i = 4 To UBound(Lineas)
   Textos = Split(Lineas(i), "|")
     For ii = 0 To UBound(Textos)
      Hoja2.Range("A1").Offset(Fila, ii).Value = Textos(ii)
     Next ii
      Fila = Fila + 1
  Next i

Next

End Sub
```

saludos

Comment: Buenos días amigo, muchas gracias por el apoyo, ya copia todas las filas según el rango que le indique pero sigue copiando todo el encabezado de cada fila, te adjunto un ejemplo de imagen lo que está en amarillo es lo que no debería copiar por que son encabezados, quiero saber si es posible o ya lo haría de forma manual:                     Link :  https://share.icloud.com/photos/0b2mKj4qwrxw_1VFmfH6Dti6w

Comment: Nunca jamás postees varias respuestas. Edita tu respuesta original y añade el código modificado.

Comment: No agregues multiples respuestas. Borra esta respuesta, y edita la respuesta que diste.

Comment: pero... no hiciste caso ;)...

Comment: borre la primera respuesta, no me dejo editarla.